# is python os.popen robust enough to handle many request?

Tags: python

I am currently using the function below from server side
to execute client command. I found that when the clients issue many command
at the same time and command take longer to be executed, this function
return code=9. Is the any module that could solve this kind of problem?
Thanks,

```
def execute_cmd(cmd):

    output_pipe = os.popen(cmd)

    print cmd
    try:
        output = output_pipe.read()
        print output
    finally:
        code = output_pipe.close()


    if code is None:
        code = 0

    return (code, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `subprocess` module is the latest and best way to run sub-processes in Python.  You may have better success with it.